# How long should a gpg key used for signing rpms be valid?

Tags: fedora, redhat, rpm, gnupg

red hat and fedora both use a new key per release and appear to support that key forever. I remember reading that the key should expire but it depended on what it was used for.

Answer (score 1):

Expiration dates on public keys is optional, although considered a "best practice" (as is creating a revocation certificate).  It is completely up to the owner of the key whether or not to set an expiration date.

A web search for "gpg key expire" [found this article](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/11/01/change-expiration-date-gpg-key/) that may help answer other questions.